# Using selenium to click ajax button

Tags: python, ajax, selenium

I'm trying to understand how to interact on a site with an ajax element. I'm using selenium+phantomJS to click the "More" button which has this code:

```
<a class="js-cne-ajax cne-more-button cne-more-videos cne-light-button" data-ajaxurl="/genres/Books.js?page=2" rel="nofollow" href="javascript:void(0)">More</a>
```

I'm using this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
next_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.js-cne-ajax.cne-more-button.cne-more-videos.cne-light-button")))
next_link.click()
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
```

My problem is that the element seems not clickable. Can it be because is the css selector wrong or, in some way, the ajax pages needs different approach? Can the "rel=nofollow" create some problems?

Comment: Do you get an exception or just nothing happens after `click()`?

Comment: Simply nothing happens

Comment: can you try `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", next_link)`

Comment: It gives me the same result: nothing happens :(

Comment: Can you share page `URL`?

Comment: http://video.newyorker.com/genres/Books

Comment: Both approaches (simple `click()` and `JS` `click()`) works fine for me with `PhantomJS`

Comment: !!! I have no idea why it doesn't with me... I've python 2.7, selenium 2.48 and phantomJS 2.1. At least I know there's no error in the code...

Comment: I tried with `Python 3.5` + `selenium 3.0.2` + `PhantomJS 2.1.1`